# What is Yoda sitting next to during Luke's training?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, luke-skywalker, object-identification, yoda

What is Yoda sitting next to while he is training Luke? Is it a pair of blue jeans? I don't recall seeing Luke bring any blue apparel to Dagobah.

[image: Yoda with blue jeans]

Comment: It's Luke's backpack.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Thank you!

Comment: When 900 years old you are, [mom jeans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aVxNH6iN9I) will you wear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It's the [backpack](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke%27s_Backpack)<sup>1</sup> in which Luke carried Yoda**

[image] [image]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>: warning - Legends link!</sub>

Comment: ... *Gundark-skin* backpack...

Comment: That's Legends, at least according to Wookieepedia.

Comment: What a cute little Jedi master.